# SAL annotations and new operator overload

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, annotations

I have problem with SAL annotations and new operator overloading. I want to provide new operator that does not throws exceptions but return nullptr in case of error. I have written:

```
_Check_return_ _Ret_maybenull_ _Success_(return != nullptr) void* operator new(_In_ size_t size)
{
    return malloc(size);
}
```

Unfortunately VS2012 see declaration of new provided in <new> header which is different and after Build->Run Code Analysis gives me a lot of errors that declarations are incompatible. Moreover it chooses a declaration provided in <new> which indicates that new never returns null. I have tried to remove <new> include but it does not help (it is included by different headers like <vector>). How can I convince compiler to use my SAL annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just link with [`nothrownew.obj`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kftdy56f.aspx), if the non-throwing new is what you really want?

Be aware though that it's generally a bad idea. For one thing, the STL implementation shipped with MSVC doesn't expect `new` to return `NULL` and doesn't check for that, but goes right ahead and uses the pointer. If you use STL, and if you do run out of memory, then instead of `bad_alloc` exception you'll get an access violation - hardly an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the STL types like  requires C++ exception handling to be fully valid (/EHsc). You can use it without it, but it's definitely a risky situation. You can use nothrownew.obj, but it's not recommended.

For cases where you are calling new and you want it to return null rather than throw exceptions, in C++11 (VS 2010 or later) the solution is to use the (std::nowthrow) version of new.

```
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> temp( new (std::nothrow) uint8_t[ size ] );
if ( !temp )
    return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
```